# Como ler um arquivo txt enviado pelo usuário?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou aprendendo asp.net MVC e criei um formulário simples:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="municipio">Nome do Município:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="municipio" placeholder="Nome do Município">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="arquivo">Selecionar arquivo...</label>
        <input type="file" id="arquivo">
        <p class="help-block">Selecione no seu computador o arquivo BPA</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Gerar relatório</button>
</form>
```

Como faço pra ler o arquivo enviado pelo usuário e mostrar as informações em outra página?

Comment: Não serviria abrir em janela flutuante?  http://kithomepage.com//sos/Como-ler-um-arquivo-txt-enviado-pelo-usuario2.htm

Comment: Estou votando para fechar sua pergunta porque existem várias formas de fazer isso. Além de que, sua pergunta não é um problema específico, você pede pra que façamos algo.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo muito boa sua ideia ^^. Como fazer?

Comment: @jbueno bem que você poderia postar alguma das várias formas que você conhece. Não sei nenhuma, por isso criei o post. Mas Edney me ajudou bastante ^^

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo não é essa a ideia do site.

Comment: Postei uma resposta com janela flutuante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, ao postar esta resposta estou presumindo que você está utilizando ASP.NET MVC Core.

Criei uma solução extremamente simples apenas para que você possa absorver alguns conceitos básicos.

Primeiramente vamos criar os **Models RelatorioMunicipio** e **Municipio**:

```
public class RelatorioMunicipio
{
    public RelatorioMunicipio(string caminhoBaseArquivo)
    {
        CaminhoBase = caminhoBaseArquivo;
    }
    public string CaminhoBase { get; set; }
    public Municipio Municipio { get; set; }

    public string AbrirArquivo()
    {
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(CaminhoBase, Municipio.Nome + ".txt"));
    }
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
public class Municipio
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Arquivo{ get; set; }

}
```

Feito isso vamos primeiro alterar sua view onde você faz o upload do seu arquivo:

```
@model UploadArquivos.Model.Municipio

<form asp-action="GerarRelatorio" asp-controller="Home"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="municipio">Nome do Município:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Nome" as placeholder="Nome do Município">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="arquivo">Selecionar arquivo...</label>
        <input type="file" asp-for="Arquivo">
        <p class="help-block">Selecione no seu computador o arquivo BPA</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Gerar relatório</button>
 </form>
```

No exemplo realizei a criação desta view utilizando a Home e Index mesmo.
Note que marco seu form como **enctype="multipart/form-data"**, isto serve para informarmos ao ASP.NET que seu form irá trabalhar com upload de arquivos.

A instrução **@model ....Municipio** indica que estamos trabalhando com um objeto deste tipo passado pela action a sua View, isso possibilita utilizarmos os comandos **asp-for="NomeDaPropriedade"**, fazendo com que em seu post os campos sejam mapeados automaticamente para as propriedades.

Agora vamos para as controllers:
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using UploadArquivos.Model;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using System.IO;
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        IHostingEnvironment Enviroment { get; set; }

```
    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment enviroment)
    {
        Enviroment = enviroment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost] 
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult GerarRelatorio(Municipio municipio)
    {
        if (municipio.Arquivo != null)
        {
            // salvando arquivo em disco
            var reader = new BinaryReader(municipio.Arquivo.OpenReadStream());
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(Enviroment.WebRootPath, $"{municipio.Nome}.txt"), reader.ReadBytes((int)municipio.Arquivo.Length));
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Exibir", "Relatorio", new { nome = municipio.Nome });
    }
}
```

Na Home precisamos do **IHostingEnvironment** que está no namespace **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting**, utilizamos ele apenas para obter o caminho raiz da aplicação para salvar seu arquivo

No método GerarRelatorio perceba que informamos um parametro do tipo **Municipio**, este é atribuído automaticamente pelo Framework quando realizamos o post devido ao que falei acima.

Note que quando criamos seu model **Municipio** além do nome criamos uma propriedade do tipo **IFormFile** chamada Arquivo, é nesta propriedade que o ASP.NET irá atribuir o arquivo postado, e com ela em mãos salvamos em disco com o método WriteAllBytes.

Feito isso redirecionamos para sua Action **Exibir** na Controller **Relatorio** informando o nome do município como parâmetro.

E na controller Relatorio temos:

```
public class RelatorioController : Controller
{
    IHostingEnvironment Enviroment { get; set; }

    public RelatorioController(IHostingEnvironment enviroment)
    {
        Enviroment = enviroment;
    }

    [Route("Relatorio/Exibir/{nome}")]
    public IActionResult Exibir(string nome)
    {
        RelatorioMunicipio relatorio = new RelatorioMunicipio(Enviroment.WebRootPath);
        relatorio.Municipio = new Municipio() { Nome = nome };
        return View(relatorio);
    }
}
```

Aqui apenas iniciamos um objeto do tipo RelatorioMunicipio preenchendo suas propriedades. Mas assim como na Home, eu necessito informar a **WebRootPath** para informar ao objeto onde ele deve procurar o arquivo.

Por fim temos a View do relatorio

```
@model UploadArquivos.Model.RelatorioMunicipio

<h1>@Model.Municipio.Nome</h1>

@Model.AbrirArquivo()
```

Nela simplesmente informamos o tipo de dados que irá ser tratado, exibimos o nome do munícipio e obtemos o arquivo gerado.

Para melhor entendimento publiquei este projeto no GitHub, faça o **[download](https://github.com/EdneySilva/StackOverFlow/tree/master/UploadArquivos)** e qualquer dúvida poste nos comentários.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Biblioteca: vc pode pegar em   [github](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script language="javascript" src="/colorbox/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript" src="/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/colorbox/colorbox.css" media="screen" />
<style>#ajax{height:510px; width:640px;}</style>
```

Script

```
window.onload = function() {

    var arquivo = document.getElementById('arquivo');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

    arquivo.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = arquivo.files[0];
        var textType = /text.*/;

        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;

            }
                $.colorbox({inline:true, href:".ajax"});
                reader.readAsText(file);    
        } else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
        }
    });
 }
```

HTML

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="municipio">Nome do Município:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="municipio" placeholder="Nome do Município">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="arquivo">Selecionar arquivo...</label>
    <input type="file" id="arquivo">
</div>
</form>
<div style='display:none'>
<div id='ajax' class='ajax'>
<div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
<div id='fileDisplayArea' class='div1'><div>
</div>
</div>
```